# How do you justify a nav whose who has class flex-column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How do you justify a nav to the right/end whose who has class flex-column in Boostrap 4? I tried

```
<div class="nav justify-content-end flex-column">
```

but the nav items still justify to the left

Comment: Post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you read up on which _axis_ control the _horizontal_ alignment in flex _column_ direction, you'll see it is **not** the `justify-content` property that should be used ... it is `align-items`

Answer (score 0):

**`justify-content-end` works perfectly for me. See my examples:**

On the `navbar-collapse` div:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Works also for the nav element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="nav justify-content-end">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</nav>
```